# How to configure multiple laravel projects on local server (Apache, Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

In our local network we are connected to an Ubuntu 16.04 server (Apache). We connect to it through local ip: `10.0.x.x` and the default apache config serves whats inside `/var/www/html`, I have tweeked the config to serve `/var/www/app-1` so when I visit `10.0.x.x` I got my app running, I was wondering how to make the apache serve other apps like `/var/www/app-2` and I maybe visit `10.0.x.x/app-2`. I know how to configure this live with domains as I point the domain 'serverName' to the rootDocument I want, but now this is local server and no domains, how to get this done?

Comment: As you are working locally, you can use run multiple laravel app in different ports.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your httpd.conf like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/app-1"
        ServerName web1.example.com:80
        ServerAdmin info@example.com
</VirtualHost>                           
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/app-2"
        ServerName web2.example.com:80
        ServerAdmin info@example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And edit your /etc/hosts files if you don't want to run a local network name server.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found [Apache virtual hosts on digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

And step 6 is what I needed 'that case I don't need actual domains'.